# What is the alternative to Route::filter in Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I would like to require login for all pages, except `/index` and `/login`. I tried to solve it like this:

```
Route::filter('pattern: ^(index|login)*', 'auth');
```

In laravel 8 `Route::filter` is not available anymore. How to solve this issue, without putting every route definition into a large group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a middleware group in your routes/web.php file.

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group( function () {

    // Your protected routes here

});
```

Alternatively you can make middleware exceptions for routes:

```
// In your auth middleware that extends Authenticate

...

/**
 * Routes that should skip handle.
 *
 * @var array $except
 */
protected array $except;


public function __construct()
{
    $this->except = [
        route('index'),
        route('login')
    ];
}


/**
 * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 */
public function handle( Request $request )
{
    $current_route = $request->route();

    if( in_array($current_route, $this->except ) {
        // Route doesn't need to be guarded
    }

}

...
```

If you don't want to have large groups then you can specify the middleware per route (can look messy)

```
Route::get('/route', [FooController::class, 'index'])->middleware('auth');
```

Comment: How to solve this issue, without putting every route definition into a large group?

Comment: @IterAtor If you don't want to use large groups then you have to specify the middleware per route.

Comment: @IterAtor Edit middleware approach in answer